# How should I reference sn.exe in msbuild script?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, code-signing, assembly-signing

I need to re-sign my assembly after the build has finished (and I've done some other things to it), so I started by adding an `<Exec>` Task that called `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sn.exe`. This has to work for other developers/environments, so I was hoping I could just copy `sn.exe` and `sn.exe.config` from that folder and store it in our code repository so I could always call a common version of it from a known location.

`sn.exe` crashes in isolation outside of the sdk directory, so I'm wondering how I can reference it without knowing what path it will be under. Different people have different environments (x86 vs x64, different install directories, different versions), so I would like to be able to easily reference the latest version of the tool (or perhaps any version). Seems like a simple enough tool, perhaps there is another way to sign an assembly with another tool/command/msbuild task? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The sn.exe has a config file associated with it. It also crashes I've noticed if you don't supply any arguments to the exe

Comment: I've tried copying sn.exe.config along with it and that didn't seem to work either. Doesn't even let me run `sn.exe -h` for the help info without crashing.

Comment: You could try download [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see if there are any dependencies missing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To properly reference a tool like `sn` or `sqlmetal` (what I am after) in an msbuild script in the way that will work for the most people, you must take into consideration different aspects of the operating environment and framework implementation. There are two main cases: Microsoft Windows and Microsoft’s implementation of the framework followed by everything else (by which I mean Mono/unix). An example of the correct approach which supports the situations I can think of is listed at the end.

### Microsoft

The proper way to find where `sn` or other similar tools live in Windows is to start with the [GetFrameworkSdkPath task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164298), as [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12822416/429091).

However, as the question suggests, the exact location within the FrameworkSdkPath that `sn` or another tool lives cannot be determined directly. The referenced answer suggests that the only possible folders under FrameworkSdkPath for tools to reside in are `bin` and `bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools`. However, other values are possible (Visual Studio 2013 Preview uses `bin/NETFX 4.5.1 Tools`). Thus, the only proper way to search for `sn` is to use a glob expression or recursively search for it. I have trouble figuring out how to do glob expansion with MSBuild and the built-in MSBuild tasks do not seem to support searching under FrameworkSdkPath for particular utilities. However, cmd’s [`WHERE`](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) has this functionality and can be used to do the search. The result is something like the following msbuild code:

```
<Target Name="GetSNPath" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild">
  <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
    <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="WindowsSdkPath" />
  </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
  <Exec Command="WHERE /r &quot;$(WindowsSdkPath.TrimEnd('\\'))&quot; sn &gt; sn-path.txt"  />
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="sn-path.txt">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" PropertyName="SNPath"/>
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <Delete Files="sn-path.txt" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SNPath>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace('$(SNPath)', ';.*', ''))</SNPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

(See [Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440#BKMK_String) to see why I can use `String.TrimEnd` here. `WHERE` doesn’t like trailing slashes. EDIT: I added use of Property Functions to access `Regex.Replace()` to delete all but the first found path in the `SNPath` property. One of my friend’s machines’s `WHERE` invocations would output multiple results for certain commands and broke any attempt to `<Exec/>` the fond tool. This change ensures that only one result is found and that `<Exec/>`s actually succeed.)

Now you can invoke `sn` with `<Exec Command="&quot;$(SNPath)&quot;" />`.

### Portable

Unsurprisingly, resolving the path to `sn` is much simpler on any operating system other than Windows. On Mac OSX and any distribution of Linux, I find `sn` in the PATH. Using `GetFrameworkSdkPath` does not help in such a situation; in fact, this seems to return a path under which `sn` cannot be found, at least for the old versions of mono-2.10 I tested while using xbuild:

- On Mac OSX `FrameworkSdkPath` is `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.5/lib/mono/2.0` and `/usr/bin/sn` is a symlink to `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/sn`.
- On a certain Linux install, `FrameworkSdkPath` is `/usr/lib64/mono/2.0` and `sn` is `/usr/bin/sn` (which is a shell script invoking `/usr/lib64/mono/4.0/sn.exe` with `mono`).

Thus, all we need to do is try to execute `sn`. Any unix users placing their `sn` implementations in non-standard places already know to update PATH appropriately, so the build script has no need to ever search for it. Also, `WHERE` does not exist in unix. Thus, in the unix case, we want to replace the first `<Exec/>` call with something that will output just `sn` on unix and still do the full search when run on Windows. To differentiate unix-like and Windows environments, we use a trick which takes advantage of unix shells’ shortcut for the `true` commmand and cmd’s label syntax. As a short example, the following script will output `I’m unix!` in a unix shellout and `I’m Windows :-/` on a Windows shellout.

```
:; echo 'I’m unix!'; exit $?
echo I’m Windows :-/
```

Taking advantage of this, our resulting `GetSNPath` Task looks like:

```
<Target Name="GetSNPath" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild">
  <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
    <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="WindowsSdkPath" />
  </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
  <Exec Command=":; echo sn &gt; sn-path.txt; exit $?
WHERE /r &quot;$(WindowsSdkPath.TrimEnd('\\'))&quot; sn &gt; sn-path.txt"  />
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="sn-path.txt">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" PropertyName="SNPath"/>
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <Delete Files="sn-path.txt" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SNPath>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace('$(SNPath)', ';.*', ''))</SNPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

The result is a portable method for finding the string required to invoke `sn`. This last solution lets you support both Microsoft and its msbuild and every other platform using xbuild. It also overcomes hardcoding `bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools` into .csproj files to support future and current versions of Microsoft tools simultaneously.

Comment: Definitely a more thorough answer than my original one. +1.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out there's a task called "GetFrameworkSdkPath" that will get the Windows SDK location. From there, I had to test to see if sn.exe existed directly in the `bin` folder, or if it's in `bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\`. Seems reliable so far.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SNExePath>NotSet</SNExePath>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- Sometimes theres nothing in the WindowsSdkPath dir and there's stuff in a deeper folder called 'NETFX 4.0 Tools'. -->
<Target Name="GetSNPath" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild">
  <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
    <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="WindowsSdkPath" />
  </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SNExePath>$(WindowsSdkPath)bin\sn.exe</SNExePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SNExePath Condition="!Exists($(SNExePath))">$(WindowsSdkPath)bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sn.exe</SNExePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>  

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Exec Command="$(SNExePath) -R $(TargetPath) $(SignatureFile)" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 2):

The method I'm using at the moment involves using a property function to perform a search for SN.exe underneath the framework SDK path - ala:

```xml
<GetFrameworkSDKPath>
  <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="DotNetFrameworkDir"/>
</GetFrameworkSDKPath>

<PropertyGroup>
  <SNPath>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("$(DotNetFrameworkDir)", "sn.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)[0])</SNPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So far I've only tested this personally on Visual Studio 2013, but the documentation implies it ought to work back to Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an environment variable on each development machine that references the executable, which MSBuild lets you reference as a property.

So, create the environment variable via the advanced tab of system properties. I usually just create a system environment variable as opposed to one scoped to the current user. You will have to restart Visual Studio for it to pick it up.

Then, reference it in MSBuild:

```
<Exec Command="$(SnExe)">
```

Where `SnExe` is the environment variable you defined.

Comment: This is not very portable and requires machine-level change to allow the build to run. The target here is to allow a machine-agnostic way of finding tools from the .NET sdk.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth the $(SDK40ToolsPath) variable worked for me in a similar situation. This negates the need to know which specific version of the tools are installed eg:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <XsdExePath>$(SDK40ToolsPath)xsd.exe</XsdExePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <xsd Include="Objects.xsd" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(XsdExePath)&quot; @(xsd) /c /namespace:Blah.Objects" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Path to a .NET Framwork tool like sn.exe is actually a combination of using GetFramworkSDKPath (as described above) and (almost) the TargetFrameworkVersion (as is specified in the project file). You basically need to remove the initial "v" from TargetFrameworkVersion and concatenate together the pieces to to form the path to the tool, for instance

```xml
<Target Name="GetSNPath" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild">
  <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
    <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="WindowsSdkPath" />
  </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
  <PropertyGroup>
  
   <FrameworkVersion>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace('$(TargetFrameworkVersilon)', 'v', ''))</FrameworkVersion>
    <NETFXVersion>NETFX $(FrameworkVersion) Tools</NETFXVersion>
    <SNPath>$(WindowsSdkPath)bin\$(NETFXVersion)\sn.exe</SNPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```